# Seeking passwordless user-level encryption service without developer key access

Tags: encryption, cloud-service, saas, angular, openid

I am looking for a scalable encryption solution for a SaaS product used by approximately 40,000 users across 5000 organizations. Our application is an Angular SPA with a C# backend, and we are integrating Auth0 for authentication.

Our current encryption strategy relies on user passwords, which is proving to be problematic for several reasons:

1. User data is lost if they forget their password, which is unacceptable.
2. We need to generate temporary passwords for data access, which users must change upon first login.
3. With Auth0's universal login, we don't have access to user passwords, potentially requiring users to remember two sets of credentials.
4. Most users authenticate via SSO and don't have a dedicated password, making it cumbersome to request an additional one for encryption purposes.

We require a solution that offers user- or organization-level encryption without developers having access to the keys. It's essential that users never lose access to their data, even if they forget a password. Also, the users don't have fixed devices; they access the SaaS product across multiple laptops, often sharing computers with other users.

We've explored several services, but each has its downsides:

- Virgil Security seemed promising, but it appears to require a user password and lacks Angular support. Additionally, their support hasn't responded to inquiries.
- HashiCorp Vault Secrets offers user-level encryption and Auth0 integration, but at $0.50 per user/month, it's too costly.
- AWS KMS and Azure KMS are also expensive at $1 per user/month.
- Google KMS is more affordable at $0.06 per key, which might work with one key per organization. However, encryption must be done through the backend, and there's a concern about developer access to keys in the dashboard.
- IronCore Labs Data Control Platform requires a password and is priced at $0.20 per user/group per month, plus a base fee of $200.
- AWS Secrets Manager doesn't seem suitable for our needs, and there's a risk of console access revealing the secrets.

Does anyone know of a service that meets these criteria? Ideally, the service would provide a way to ensure data recovery even if a user forgets their password, without compromising on security or significantly increasing costs.